# How to break from a loop in Maxima

Tags: maxima, wxmaxima

I am new to Maxima. I am trying to write a loop in that I am checking if some condition met then exit from the loop.

```
cp:for i:1 step 1 thru 10 do
block(if(i>6) then break()
else
print(i,"is less than 6"));
```

I want output: 
1 is less than 6 
2 is less than 6 
3 is less than 6 
4 is less than 6 
5 is less than 6 
6 is less than 6

But when I am running the above code :

after printing 6 is less than 6, it is prompting
**Entering a Maxima break point. Type 'exit;' to resume.**
and after typing exit; it will again show the above msg

I want the code will come out completely from that loop rather than asking to type exit;

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 3):

Try `return(i)` instead of `break()`. Also, `return` only returns from the block which encloses it, so you need to remove the `block(...)` in your example (it's unneeded anyway). I think this works:

```
cp: for i:1 step 1 thru 10 
      do if(i>6) then return(i) else print(i,"is less than 6");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I tried. It works but it's still not very elegant though:

```
flag:1;
for k : 1 while k<=10*flag do 
    if (k>3) then (
        print("break !"),
        flag:0)
else 
    print (flag,k);
```